# Access denied issue in Active Directory Ldap

Tags: active-directory

I am creating a user in an active directory with lap connection (c#) from server 1 OU to another server OU with User (Domain user) having permission to create / set password , created through delegate wizard.
e.g.

```
PrincipalContext newContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
             "LdapPath:389", oupath, 
             ContextOptions.SimpleBind, username, password);

UserPrincipal newUserPricipal = 
    new UserPrincipal(newContext, 
                      Convert.ToString(result.Properties["SAMAccountName"][0]), 
                      "somerandompassword", true);
newUserPricipal.Save();
```

User details with all properties get synced but set password throws Access denied exception.

I cannot make user administrator or domain admin as per policy. This worked with Windows Server 2012 R2. But not in Windows Server 2016. Why?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve "**Access denied exception**", please try below workarounds:

- Ensure the user has the permission of changing password. Check if **"user cannot change the password"** is not selected on DC.
- ***Go to Active Directory Users and Computers ->View -> Advanced Features -> Properties -> Security -> SELF -> Change Password -> OK***
- Ensure that **allow permission** is enabled for that user.
- Check the permissions of actual user OU or sub-OU in Active Directory.
- Ensure that the user or group you are delegating to is listed correctly.
- Run the delegation wizard on the correct OU and check the "**Reset user password**" option.
- Check if the user is a member of certain **built-in AD groups** like Account Operators or Backup Operators.
- Ensure that the `admincount` attribute is set to 0. If it is 1, then it means user is a member of a protected group.

**References:**

[Access Denied when trying to change password on not domain joined Windows 2016 server from domain joined Windows (microsoft.com)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/224893c9-500f-465b-86ee-47ff859fbd41/access-denied-when-trying-to-change-password-on-not-domain-joined-windows-2016-server-from-domain)

[Access Denied error when trying to reset AD password from an IIS site (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6c0f1ee-b498-4805-851d-ca5a580e27f0/access-denied-error-when-trying-to-reset-ad-password-from-an-iis-site?forum=aspactivedirectory)

Comment: It didnt work.The above code perfectly worked in windows server 2012 r2 , but gives access denied in win server 2016. It doesnt if user is made domain admin. We cant make sync user who is setting password of other users the domain admin but can give permissions which we have already given.